# Chrome extension gives feedback by comparing URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making chrome extension. This is a program that checks whether a particular site is right by comparing the URL when you access Google. 
The thing I want to do is compare URLs and send an alert when I connect.

However, it does not take effect until you click the chrome extension program. Please let me know the event you need.

main.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
code: 'document.URL;'
}, function (domain) {
var google = 'https://www.google.co.kr/';
if(domain == google){
    alert('is google')
}
else
    alert('not google')
})
```

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "site detect",
"description": "site",
"version": "1.0",
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
]
}
```

Comment: The popup runs only when the icon is clicked. Otherwise it doesn't. You need to use a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) event listener to check the URL. You won't need executeScript to get the URL as it'll be presented inside the listener's `tab` parameter.

Comment: about this? chrome.tabs.onUpdated({
    code: 'document.URL;'
}, function (domain) {
    var google = 'https://www.google.co.kr/';
    if(domain == google){
        alert('is google')
    }
    else
        alert('not google')
})

this is background scripts

Comment: That's invalid code. Look at the documentation and find examples using google search or similar service.